# Transforming aspect values in order to use them in multiple regression models

Tags: arcgis-desktop, regression

I want to use aspect as an independent variable in a multiple regression model but I would like to transform the aspect values so that from degrees 180 to 360, I would get their equivalent to degrees from 0 to 180. How could I do that in ArcGIS or R?

Comment: If you have aspect raster computed, why not to use con ("Aspect" >= 180,"Aspect"-180,"Aspect") in raster calculator

Comment: The most straightforward way is to [take the aspect modulo 180](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Mod/009z00000094000000/).  As Dr. Evans' answer suggests, though, that should only be the start of your modeling procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I have several methods available in our [Geomorphometry and Gradient Metrics Toolbox](http://evansmurphy.wix.com/evansspatial#!arcgis-gradient-metrics-toolbox/crro) (Evans et al., 2014). From your description it sounds like the "Linear Aspect" or "Classify Aspect" tools would work for you. However, I have found that, in regression models, other transformations are much more effective.

The Roberts & Cooper (1989) method unfolds and recenters aspect so that 0 represents north- northeast aspects, (typically the coolest and wettest orientation) and 1 represents hotter, dryer south-southwesterly aspects. The Stage (1976) transformations are an interaction between slope and aspect and have proven to be robust indicators of topographically driven a biotic ecological process. The McCune & Keon (2002) Heat Load Index also represents a slope/aspect interaction but is scaled to represent solar isolation.

The methodology for unfolding or "linearizing" aspect, in ArcGIS raster algebra, are:

```
tmp1=Aspect(dem)
tmp2=SetNull(tmp1 < 0,(450.0 - tmp1) / 57.296)
tmp3=Sin(tmp2)
tmp4=Cos(tmp2)
tmp5=FocalStatistics(tmp3,NbrRectangle(3,3,"CELL"),"SUM","DATA")
tmp6=FocalStatistics(tmp4,NbrRectangle(3,3,"CELL"),"SUM","DATA")
tmp7 = Mod(((450 - (ATan2(tmp5, tmp6) * 57.296)) * 100), 36000) / 100
outRaster = Con((tmp5 == 0) & (tmp6 == 0),- 1, tmp7)
```

**References**

Evans JS, Oakleaf J, Cushman SA, Theobald D (2014) An ArcGIS Toolbox for Surface Gradient and Geomorphometric Modeling, version 2.0-0. Available: http://evansmurphy.wix.com/evansspatial.

McCune, B. & D. Keon., (2002). Equations for potential annual direct incident radiation and heat load index. Journal of Vegetation Science. 13:603-606.

Stage, A.R., (1976). An Expression of the Effects of Aspect, Slope, and Habitat Type on Tree Growth. Forest Science 22(3):457-460.

Roberts. D.W., and Cooper, S.V., (1989). Concepts and techniques of vegetation mapping. In Land Classifications Based on Vegetation: Applications for Resource Management. USDA Forest Service GTR INT-257, Ogden, UT, pp 90-96

Comment: Thank you very much Jeffrey! So is it reclassification what you suggest?

Comment: Sorry, no I meant the "linear aspect" tool. I modified my answer to reflect this a provide the methodology to do this outside of my toolbox.

Comment: I have applied what you suggested but I can't understand how this will is taking care of the issue of repeating values from 180 to 360 when I want to use the aspect values as an independent variable in my regression model. My values are from 1-359.

Comment: The variable is no longer circular.

Comment: could this same procedure you gave above for transforming circular aspect to linear aspect work for the GRASS GIS raster calculator as well? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the formula is almost the same - consider to write it as a single r.mapcalc call using the eval() function which allows to concatenate several equations.