# Linearising aspect in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, coordinate-system, regression, aspect

After having produced aspect of surface in GRASS GIS and being aware that GRASS GIS calculates aspect counterclockwise from east, how could we transform aspect from being a circular variable (0-360 degrees) into being a linear variable, so it can be used as explanatory variable in multiple regression models. I am aware of this answer ([Transforming aspect values in order to use them in multiple regression models](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138441/transforming-aspect-values-in-order-to-use-them-in-multiple-regression-models)) which works perfectly in ArcGIS. How could the same procedure be carried out in GRASS GIS?

Comment: If you were to ask this at [stats.SE] you might get some creative answers ranging from splines through various other transformations. They key is to obtain a set of independent variables that are likely to be linearly related to the dependent variable.